# Inverse of $x\sinh x$

Tags: closed-form, inverse-function

I'm looking for a closed expression for the inverse of $$f(x)=x\cdot\sinh x\,.$$ It looks like there should be some combination of Lambert $W$ functions that would do it, but I can't seem to find a solution.

In the application I'm considering, $x$ is real and positive (but not very large).

Comment: Possibly generalized W function, but I'm quite positive the normal one won't apply here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There is no closed solution with the known classical functions.*

If one defines $\,f(x):=(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})^x\geq 1\,$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}\,$ , $\,f(-x)=f(x)\,$ ,

and $\,f^{-1}(x)\,$ is his inverse for $\,x\geq 0$, then it's possible to solve $\,y=x\sinh x\,$ : $$x_{1,2}=\pm \sinh^{-1} f^{-1}(e^y)$$

---

*Note:*

It's a bit like $\,y=g(x):=1+x^2\ge 1\,$ with $\,x_{1,2}=\pm g^{-1}(y)=\pm\sqrt{y-1}\,$ .

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x)=x\sinh(x)=x\ \left(\frac{1}{2}e^x-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\right)$$

$f$ is an algebraic function of $x$ and $e^x$. Liouville and Ritt proved that such kind of functions doesn't have elementary inverses.

$$x\sinh(x)=y$$
$$x\sinh(x)-y=0$$
$$x\ \left(\frac{1}{2}e^x-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\right)-y=0$$
$$\frac{1}{2}x\left(e^x\right)^2-ye^x-\frac{1}{2}x = 0$$
Because the degree of this exponential polynomial for $e^x$ is greater than $1$, the equation cannot be solved in terms of Lambert W.

The inverse of $f$ is presented in:
[Vazquez-Leal, H.; Sandoval-Hernandez, M. A.; Filobello-Ninoa, U.: The novel family of transcendental Leal-functions with applications to science and engineering. Heliyon 6 (2020) (11) e05418](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2405844020322611)

see also: [What are the closed-form inverses of $x \sinh(x), x \cosh(x), x \tanh(x), x\ \text{sech}(x), x \coth(x), x\ \text{csch}(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4602072/what-are-the-closed-form-inverses-of-x-sinhx-x-coshx-x-tanhx-x-te)

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @IV_’s answer, here is a [Lagrange reversion](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjGve33r4b8AhXjrHIEHY7FAkEQFnoECBAQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLagrange_reversion_theorem&usg=AOvVaw0Ywh3pLNY60VuwcRMItE3g) result:

$$y\sinh(y)=x\implies y=x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{ n!}\frac{d^{n-1}\left(\frac{xe^{-x}}2-\frac{xe^x}2+x\right)^n}{dx^{n-1}}$$

roughly [shown](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5Bx+sinh%28x%29%2C10%5D%2Cx%3Dlim+a-%3E0.3+%28a%2B+sum%5B1%5En%2Fn%21+D%5B%28a+%2B+%28e%5E%28-a%29+a%29%2F2+-+%28e%5Ea+a%29%2F2%29%5En%2C%7Ba%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C26%7D%5D%29) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7Bx+sinh%28x%29%2C+x+%3D+0.531737%7D). The next step is to use the [trinomial theorem](https://sahilmohnani.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/the-trinomial-theorem-and-pascals-tetrahedron/):

$$\frac1{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}\left(\frac{xe^{-x}}2-\frac{xe^x}2+x\right)^n}{dx^{n-1}}=\sum_{m=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{(-1)^k\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}e^{(2k-m)x}x^n}{(n-m)!(m-k)!k!2^m}$$

Here appears a [Laguerre function Rodrigues representation here in $(2)$ to $(5)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLaguerrePolynomial.html), but it is more flexible to use the [general Leibniz rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) with the [confluent hypergeometric function $\,_1\text F_1(a;b;z)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1F1):

$$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}e^{(2k-m)x}x^n=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}j \frac{d^{n-1-j}}{dx^{n-1-j}}x^n\frac {d^j}{dx^j}e^{(2k-m)x}=xn!\,_1\text F_1(n+1;2;(2k-m)x)$$

Although it converges slowly, we get:

$$\boxed{y\sinh(y)=x\implies y=\pm x\pm x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{n!(-1)^k\,_1\text F_1(n+1,2,(2k-m)x)}{(n-m)!(m-k)!k!2^m}}$$

[**shown here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y+sinh%28y%29%2Cy%3Dx%2Bsum%5Bsum%5Bsum%5Bx++%28-1%29%5Ek+n%21+1F1%281+%2B+n%2C+2%2C+%282+k+-+m%29+x%29%2F%28%28n-m%29%21%28m-k%29%21k%21+2%5Em%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C9%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C9%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C9%7D%5D%2Cx%3D0.3) in the substitution section. Additionally, $0\le m\le k\le \infty$ or $0\le k\le m\le \infty$ and if all bounds are $\infty$, then all sums are interchangeable.

Approximate graph of inverse for small $n$:

[image]

Is there any way to simplify the boxed result or find other solutions using a series?

Comment: These coefficients [diverge](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5Bcsch%28x%29%5E20%2C%7Bx%2C20-1%7D%5D+at+x%3D0.01), so the $x-x\sinh(x)$ was the argument of the derivative.